# datatable warning "unknown parameter 0"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to use datatables with a set number of columns and an array of objects I get from jQuery ajax.

I get the error:

```
datatables warning (table id = myId requested unknown parameter 0 from the data source for row 0
```

Searching the internet has shown me that it's probable I have a different number of column headers and column data in my `message_json` array;

I have 21 columns set up in my data table initialization:

```
var construct_messages_table = function(message_json){

    var oTable = $('#tableId').dataTable( {
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aaData": message_json,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "coloumn1"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn2"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn3"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn4"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn5"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn6"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn7"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn8"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn9"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn10"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn11"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn12"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn13"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn14"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn15"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn16"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn17"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn18"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn19"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn20"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn21"}

    ]
} );   

};
```

And

```
for (var i = 1; i < message_json.length; i++){
   console.log(Object.keys(message_json[i]).length);

}

shows all objects have a length of 21. What could be wrong here?
```

EDIT:

I've removed nulls as that might be the problem, but still no help.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < message_json.length; i++){

        for (var o in message_json[i]){

           if (message_json[i][o] == null){
               message_json[i][o] = "";
           }

        }

    }
```

EDIT:
`message_json` is in this format

```
    [
{type: "int",
id: "111",
name: "co",
description: "",
is_bool: "0",
keyword: "<tag name=&quot;various-xml&quot;>fields</xml>",
message: "hello",
temp: "world",
settings: "",
priority: "100",
enabled: "0",
secure: "1",
var1: "post",
var1_desc: "some desc↵",
var1_query: "<DATA>blah</DATA>",
prop: "1",
prop_name: "Draft",
transaction: "1",
users: "0",
table_name: "abc"},   

{type: "int",
id: "111",
name: "co",
description: "",
is_bool: "0",
keyword: "<tag name=&quot;various-xml&quot;>fields</xml>",
message: "hello",
temp: "world",
settings: "",
priority: "100",
enabled: "0",
secure: "1",
var1: "post",
var1_desc: "some desc↵",
var1_query: "<DATA>blah</DATA>",
prop: "1",
prop_name: "Draft",
transaction: "1",
users: "0",
table_name: "abc"}];
```

But with lots more elements of course. And not just a duplicates.

Comment: The missing comma on the coloum11 is a typo?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Yes, from when I was changing from my actual column names. I'll correct it in the question. Oops.

Comment: Could you provide the aaData?

Comment: You're providing a aaData with 20 object properties but you mention in you question that the length shown by the Object.keys is 21 ?

Comment: I know that i ask for too much things but could you please provide the html of the table to see it or a jsfiddle

Comment: @EduardoQuintana The table is simply `<table id="tableId"></table>`. DataTable should just insert it in there. When I replace all the columns' keys (formerly `sTitle`) with `mData`, the rows from the array of objects show up, but no column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the number of elements must be the same as the columns otherwise `Datatables` will look for a value not included in the data.

If you want to use a structure like the one in:

```
    [
{type: "int",
id: "111",
name: "co",
description: "",
is_bool: "0",
keyword: "<tag name=&quot;various-xml&quot;>fields</xml>",
message: "hello",
temp: "world",
settings: "",
priority: "100",
enabled: "0",
secure: "1",
var1: "post",
var1_desc: "some desc↵",
var1_query: "<DATA>blah</DATA>",
prop: "1",
prop_name: "Draft",
transaction: "1",
users: "0",
table_name: "abc"},   

{type: "int",
id: "111",
name: "co",
description: "",
is_bool: "0",
keyword: "<tag name=&quot;various-xml&quot;>fields</xml>",
message: "hello",
temp: "world",
settings: "",
priority: "100",
enabled: "0",
secure: "1",
var1: "post",
var1_desc: "some desc↵",
var1_query: "<DATA>blah</DATA>",
prop: "1",
prop_name: "Draft",
transaction: "1",
users: "0",
table_name: "abc"}];
```

It will be better to use  [**"sAjaxSource"**](http://datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource) on your `dataTable`

When you add the `aaData` to your datatables normally they provide an array of arrays:
Example:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp7b4/)

If your want to use a `key:value` `JSON` object you will need to add the [**mData**](http://datatables.net/ref#mData) property to your `aoColumms` config like this:

```
var oTable = $('#tableId').dataTable( {
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "aaData": message_json,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "coloumn1","mData":"type"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn2","mData":"id"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn3","mData":"name"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn4","mData":"description"},
        { "sTitle": "coloumn5","mData":"is_bool"},...
```

This will tell datatables where to find the value for that column.